# NoSQL databases (maps)

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

I am starting to look into NoSQL databases.
I think I got the main concept which is to store the data as "maps" i.e. as key-value pairs which the NoSQL distinguishes via a unique id.

At this point I am confused (in relation to when designing the database).

Does this (that the data are stored as "maps") imply that the data we store in a Collection of a NoSQL must be "homogenous"?
Same as a `Map` in `Java` for instance where the keys are all of the same type and the values are all of the same type?

Also is the concept of referential integrity supported in NoSQL databases? Or Since they are stored as maps, I will have to 
write code to manually update any related collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we're talking about MongoDB:

- There is no referential integrity enforcement on the DB side. You have to do it in the application code. Triggers and cascade update/delete are also on you.
- Documents can be complex tree-like structures, where keys are strings and values can be of [different types](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification).
- Documents are not required to be homogenous. The same collection can contain documents of any structure and field set.

Comment: @ Sergio:So the referencial integrity enforcement is offered by other NoSQL databases but not by MongoDB?Is this what you mean in the first note?

Comment: @user384706: I know MongoDB pretty well. Other solutions - not so much. But, from the top of my head I can't name one of them that does this. They are called "NoSQL" for a reason :-)

Comment: @ Sergio: I see there a library called Morphias that does some ORM staff on Mongo.If I use libraries like these, won't they take care of referencial integrity?

Comment: @ Sergio: I was wondering because I see in some posts some annotations `@Reference` etc and I was wondering if this is related to foreign keys